# Given the following formula in predicate logic, determine for which valuations it holds.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The problem is the following:

"Let $\varphi := \Big(P_1(x_1,x_2) \rightarrow P_1(x_2,x_1)\Big)$ be a formula in predicate logic. Describe (in as simple form as possible) exactly which values of $v(x_1)$ and $v(x_2)$ will make $\varphi$ hold, given the following structures:

(a) $<\mathbb{Z}; ;\text{"is equal to"}>$

(b) $<\mathbb{Z}; ; \text{"is less than"}>$. "

My reasoning goes as follows:

(a) Given this structure, we wish to find valuations $v(x_1), v(x_2)$ such that
$$
v(x_1) = v(x_2) \Rightarrow v(x_2) = v(x_1).
$$
Since $v(x_1), v(x_2) \in \mathbb{Z}$; we are simply looking for integers $a,b$ such that
$$
a = b \Rightarrow b = a.
$$
But this holds for any two identical integers $a,b$. Hence, $\varphi$ holds whenever $v(x_1) = v(x_2)$ in this structure.

(b) Here, we are instead looking for integers $a,b$ such that
$$
a < b \Rightarrow b < a.
$$
But this doesn't hold for any integers $a,b$. Hence, there are no valuations $v(x_1), v(x_2)$ for which $\varphi$ holds in this structure. $\ \square$

Is this correct? If it is, should I perhaps be more formal in how I present the answer? If not, am I misunderstanding something about how to deal with interpretations in predicate logic?

Comment: What are the truth conditions for a conditional?

Comment: @TenO'Four The implication is true whenever (i) 0->0, (ii) 0->1 and (iii) 1->1 (0,1 being Booleans). Is this what you meant?

Comment: so the conditional is true when the antecedent is false...

Comment: @TenO'Four Ah! Which means I need to modify my answer to take this into consideration. I guess the answer to (a) would then be: "phi holds whenever: v(x1)=v(x2), or when v(x1) (not =) v(x2)"?